# How to allow user to paste spreadsheet data (multiple columns) into a textarea

Tags: reactjs, input, textarea

Im working on a system which should allow the user to copy data from a spreadsheet and paste into an inputfield(text area). Each row received should then be handled as an object with x properties within.

For example

```
{
  emailaddress: xxx@xxx.com,
  firstname: Siri,
  lastname: Hemsley,
  address: 154 Example Dr, Hendersonville NC
}
```

I have seen that Mailchimp is using something very similar but not sure how it's done.

I'm mostly using react and various npms (still a beginner)

Any suggestions or example of code that can do this?

Image of mailchimp below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you copy content from Google Spreadsheets (I am not sure about Excel etc.) an output comes with tabs `\t` between each value and new lines `\n` between each row.

You can split textarea value by *tabs* and new *lines* and transform it  to an object. Something like this:

```js
const textArea = document.querySelector('textarea');
textArea.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  const lines = e.target.value.split('\n')
  lines?.forEach(line => {
    console.log("this is one line", line);
    const values = line.split('\t');
    console.log("values of line", values);
  });
});
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

I hope it helps you somehow.

Comment: Thank you! i will try this and let you know!